# Yii Framework : Register CSS After Publishing Asset Folder

Tags: yii

Kind of new to Yii. I'm trying to publish all files under the asset folder in a view.

Structure is like this :

`/views/test`

`/views/test/assets`

`/views/test/assets/css`

`/views/test/assets/images`

Now, what I did was publish the assets folder using `Yii:app()->getAssetManager()->publish( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/assets/' );` in the `/views/test` directory.

It publishes them all right, but now I have to call `cs()->registerCssFile` for all the css contained in `/views/test/assets/css`. How do I do that?

I know that the publish() method returns the path. Does this mean I have to do a foreach $file from the folder then call `cs()->registerCssFile` using the returned asset directory?

There may be an easier way, so any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found the answer! While `registerCssFile()` does work, there's a much more elegant solution, Yii packages!

Consider the following file structure :

```
protected
\---views
   |---home
   |  \---assets
   |     |---css
   |     |  |---styles.css
   |     |  |---custom.css
   |     |  \---print.css
   |     |---js
   |     |  |---functions.js
   |     |  |---jquery.js
   |     |  \---ajax.js
   |     |---images
   |        |---img1.png
   |        |---imgn.png
   |        \---imgX.png
   \---index.php
```

You'd declare a package like so in `index.php`, taking care to use the Yii framework's dot notation for the `basePath` :

```
$package = array(
    'basePath'    => 'application.views.home.assets',
    'css'         => array( 'styles.css' ),
    'js'          => array( 'jquery.js', 'functions.js' )
);
```

Then, use Yii's `clientScript` to add and register the package.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript()
          ->addPackage( 'package-name', $package )
          ->registerPackage( 'package-name' );
```

What this will then do is publish **ALL** the contents of `basePath` and register the CSS and JS files specified in the package. For example, `styles.css`, `custom.css`, and `print.css` will all be published but only `styles.css` will be appended to the `<head>`.

Consider this rather than using :

```
$assetFolder = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/assets' );
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile( $assetFolder . 'styles.css' );
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile( $assetFolder . 'jquery.js' );
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile( $assetFolder . 'function.js' );
```

Michael is correct that there wouldn't be too many anyway so specifying the css and js files in the package declaration shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: Indeed. It also looks like Yii II is set up around packages of assets.

Comment: I had a problem with this

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is right: Yii does not look at the files in that directory. It only publishes the complete directory. It's your job to register all files that you need. You could open the directory from PHP and read in the directory content. But i'd avoid that on high-volume sites - it cost's precious CPU cycles.

I'd simply call `registerCssFile()` manually for each of those files. It shouldn't be too many anyway. And this way you have more control over which files are loaded.